# Run a command to make a directory through bash

Tags: bash, shell, quotes, mkdir

I am creating a command that when executed will automatically make a folder on my desired location and put some files in it so I can get started quickly but for some reason I am not being able to create a directory. The goal is to pass a variable for the name of the directory to be created.

I have used `mkdir` and then pass the path and file name no errors are shown but the directory is not created. I even used `eval`.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo File name:
read file

cd ~/Desktop
mkdir $file
```

I expect the directory to be created and shown.

Comment: The script should work. Please show us a sample session where you run it and then check for the directory it should have created.

Comment: To show the dir after making it, do `find . -type d -name "$file" -depth 1`

Comment: you may be looking for `mkdir -p`

Comment: i tested and this script works. May be the change directory is not working. remove that and see if the folder is getting created on the place where the script is present,. Also ensure that you have access to create a folder inside Desktop.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes:

```
mkdir "$file"
```

Example of what might happen if you do not use quotes:

```
file="hello world"
mkdir $file
```

This creates 2 directories "hello" and "world", and not the expected directory "hello world".